# Can't get children of div element in Internet Explorer -works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have looked at several questions here that seem similar but I cannot find an answer. I am trying to learn how to do "drag and drop" in pure javascript. My test code works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 10.

I am dragging two `div` elements inside a container `div` and then with a button click I am checking the values of the `id` attributes of each of the two children added.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="check.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div1 {
            width:350px;
            height:120px;
            padding:10px;
            margin-bottom:15px;
            border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }
        .box {
            display:inline;
            width:100px;
            height:30px;
            padding:10px;
            border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div class="box" id="foo" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">foo </div>
<div class="box" id="bar" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">bar </div>
<input type="button" name="check" id="check" value="Check">
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function () {

    var button = document.getElementById('check');
    button.addEventListener("click", handler, false);

    function handler() {
        var d = document.getElementById("div1");
        var children = d.childNodes;
        //var children = d.children;  tried both children and childNode : works in FF/Chrome not IE
        var i;
        document.write(children.length + "<br>");
        document.write(children[0] + "<br>");
        document.write(children[1] + "<br>");
        for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            document.write(children[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

Output in Firefox and Chrome is what I expected:

```
2
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
foobar
```

Output in IE: the child nodes are undefined:

```
2
undefined
undefined
```

I know that text nodes cannot have children but it seems that I am adding `div` elements here so I don't understand what is happening. I looked up the `.children` and `.childNode` methods and they are both supposed to be supported from IE 9 and I am testing with IE 10. Is it perhaps something to do with the `appendChild` method?

Comment: Is it any better if you use `console.log` instead of `document.write`? Modifying the document while you're inspecting it seems suspect.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I just tried console.log with IE and I get the proper response. But ultimately I want the output 'foobar' to go to the document not the console. Why is it working in FF/Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem *is* with `document.write` it replaces current document and IE reacts to it worse than the rest.

If you want to display the results on the page - dedicate a placeholder (e.g. another DIV) and add output to its innerHTML.